# Instance variables on Ruby main class

Tags: ruby

Consider the following code:

```
@name = 'learning metaprogramming!'

def cap
  @name.upcase # Was expecting to require @@name as the scopes are different like in a class
end

cap # => "LEARNING METAPROGRAMMING!"
```

Can someone explain, how come I am able to access `@name`, which I suppose should be the `class` variable of `main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@name` is an instance variable, `@@name` would be a class variable.

When you define an instance variable outside any explicit class definition, you implicitly are inside the `Object` space.

```
➜  ~  irb
2.1.5 :001 > self.class
 => Object
2.1.5 :002 >
```

`Object` is an object, more or less like a custom object. Therefore, when you created

```
@name = 'learning metaprogramming!'
```

the instance variable `@name` exists in the scope of the `Object`. The method definition happens in the same scope, hence you have accesso the instance variable.

Comment: Then what is the method `cap`? Is it the instance method or class method of `Object`?

Comment: No, `@name`, does not exist in the scope of `Object`, it exists in the scope of `main`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I know, that's why I used in the scope of *the* `Object` instead of in the scope *of* `Object`. Feel free to rephrase it if you feel it's confusing. I believe we are meaning the same thing, it is just a possible lack of English communication skills. ;)

Comment: @JikkuJose `cap` is a private instance method of `Object`.

Comment: @MarekLipka okay that sounds meaningful; but I am just finding it confusing as how the inside and outside of a method has the same scope. Won't the act of defining the method change the `self` into the current scope's instance's scope?

Comment: @JikkuJose the scope where you define your method doesn't really matter, the scope where you call your method does. And in this case, you call your method on `self` (without an explicit receiver), and for that `self` you assigned instance variable before.